# How to initialize flutter top-level variable in class and use it in top-level function

Tags: flutter, dart

There is one top-level variable.

```
int g_num = 0;
```

There is one top-level variable.

```
Future<void> _testfunction(int n) async {
  print('g_num : $g_num');
}
```

This is a simple example of outputting the value of a top-level variable from a top-level function.

Now let's initialize the top-level variable in the class.

```
int g_num = 0;

Future<void> _testfunction() async {
  print('g_num : $g_num');
}
```

```
  g_num = 1000;
  print('num : $g_num'); //1000
  await compute(_testfunction, 1); // 0
```

I initialized the top variable to 1000, but the output from `_testfunction` is 0.

I would like to know how to initialize a top level variable and retain its value.

Comment: This has nothing to do with classes.  You call `compute`, which executes the function in a separate `Isolate`.  `Isolate`s are *isolated`; they do not share memory (such as global variables).

Comment: thank you. Your hint solved the problem!